# NETGuard vs ILProtector vs AppFuscator

Tags: protection

I have some applications with written in VB.NET. I want to protect them for selling them. I want to use a paid protection. What are the order of those protectors from easier to harder ? How hard is each of them ?

Comment: sorry, we're not a review site.